# Oracle - NVL(col1,col2) Order By slowness

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-tuning

There is a column in Select clause NVL(b.name, a.name) and I am using this column in Order By due to which the Oracle query has become slow.

I tried creating index on the NAME column but of no use.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            nvl(b.name,a.name) AS b_a_name, -- Order by is using this column and hence the slowness. Index is present on NAME column but of no use
            b.name b_name,
            a.name a_name
        FROM
            employee a
            LEFT JOIN employee b ON a.parent_id = b.child_id
    )
ORDER BY b_a_name --- this Order By is taking time
;
```

I expect how to tune Order By clause or how can I re-write the query to get the same output but with improved performance.

Comment: You are ordering by a combination of columns from two tables.  I cannot think of a simple way to remove the sort, which is the cause of the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your query without using the subquery though not sure it will improve any performance or not

```
SELECT      nvl(b.name,a.name) AS b_a_name, 
            b.name a_name,
            a.name b_name
        FROM
            employee a
            LEFT JOIN employee b ON a.parent_id = b.child_id
    order by b_a_name
```

Answer (score 0):

How about removing `NVL` from `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT NVL(b.name, a.name) AS b_a_name,
       b.name a_name,
       a.name b_name
  FROM employee a
       LEFT JOIN employee b ON a.parent_id = b.child_id
  ORDER BY b.name, a.name;
```

Anyway, `ORDER BY` *will* slow things down. Unordered set is always retrieved faster.

---

By the way, why did you do that with column aliases? To confuse the enemy? Well, you confused *me*.

```
b.name a_name      --> shouldn't that be b_name
a.name b_name      -->                   a_name
```

Comment: corrected in the original question, my mistake. I tried this but no performance gain.

Comment: Your ORDER BY version will result in a different ordering compared to the OP's. If a B.NAME is null, that row will appear towards the end of the sort, even if the A.NAME is 'Aaron'. In the OP's version, using NVL, that name will be close to the top of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here the time was taken by the IO time and no degradation by (CPU time)Order By clause. I confirmed this by putting all data of query into a table and then applied Order by. All time was consumed by writing the data to table. Response time is 0.2 secs but IO time is 6 secs which cant be reduced, parallel hint may help.

Comment: You should edit your original question and add this clarification right there.